# How secure is LMS?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

LMS is a hash-based digital signature scheme. It is a standard alongside of XMSS, which has it's bit-security stated in the paper(about 200bit-security for standard parameters). LMS security assumption is based on ROM of hash functions. Does it mean the bit-security for LMS is equal to the bit-security of hash functions in QROM?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean the bit-security for LMS is equal to the bit-security of hash functions in QROM?

Well, [Edward Eaton](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/607.pdf) examines this in a multitarget setting (that is, where the adversary has been given a number of public keys (and valid signatures for those keys), and aims to produce a forgery for any one of them); his conclusion (Theorem 2, section 4.2) is that:

> Theorem 2. Let A be an adversary attacking the security of the full LMS scheme in the multi-user setting. If A makes at most q queries, then the probability they break the existential unforgeability of any of the instances of LMS is at most
> $$580q/2^{n/2}$$

Given that Grover's algorithm requires $\pi /2 \cdot 2^{n/2}$ queries (counting the compute and the uncompute operations as two separate queries), this implies that the security is no worse than $log_2(580 / (\pi/2)) \approx 8.5$ bits worse than the security of the underlying hash function against Grover's algorithm.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, LMS only allows SHA256 as a hashfunction, while XMSS can do either SHA2 or SHAKE? What is the bit security of these, in presence of the quantum computers? How does one calculate this bit security?

Comment: @namaewa: well, if they act like a random Oracle, then the bit security would be the same (however, Eaton's analysis depends on some precise details of LMS, and so it is likely different by a constant factor).  However, XMSS uses (for $n=256$) SHAKE-128; that has preimage resistance of only 128 bits (against a classical internal collision attack); I'm not certain to what extend this attack would be improved with a Quantum Computer.

Comment: so XMSS seems to have a weaker security assumption than LMS, I read in their paper that for n=32,  w=16 and SHA256 it provides 196bit security. So LMS security for the same parameters would be 256?

Comment: @namaewa: XMSS and LMS are analyzed in different security models, and so the resulting strengths are not directly comparable. If you were to ask about best known-attacks, LMS and the SHA-256 version of XMSS would be close (with XMSS getting a bit of an edge for multitarget attacks which assume a truly huge number of target public keys)